# Ist das Wort “Dutzend“ langsam veraltet?

Tags: numbers

Kommt es mir nur so vor oder wird “Dutzend“ (Zahlenmenge 12) langsam obsolet?

Comment: Was meinst du mit "obsolet" und "veraltet"? Das das Wort immer seltener verwendet wird? Dass man es nicht mehr braucht und aus dem Wörterbuch streichen sollte? Was ist die Frage?

Comment: Hängt davon ab, mit welchem früheren Zeitpunkt Du es vergleichst und was Du mit "langsam" meinst. Wir können aber schlecht in die Zukunft sehen und daher gar nicht sagen, ob es obsolet wird.

Answer (score 7):

Laut [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Dutzend&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDutzend%3B%2Cc0) wird das Wort nicht signifikant weniger benutzt in letzter Zeit, ich denke es wird nach wie vor selten aber stetig benutzt. Eine endgültige Aussage lässt sich wohl erst nach Jahren oder Jahrzehnten treffen und ist pauschal schwer zu entscheiden. Wenn auch im Handel/Verkauf vlt. seltener benutzt als früher, so ist es in Literatur und Film immer wieder anzutreffen.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Dutzend hat laut Duden derzeit zwei Bedeutungen:

1. Menge von zwölf Stück
2. (emotional) große Anzahl

Ich beobachte, dass es mit der ersten Bedeutung immer weniger verwendet wird. Wenn man 12 Eier möchte, sagt man eben zwölf. Allerdings findet das Dutzend als Zählmaß immer noch häufiger Anwendung als das Schock oder Gros (zumindest soweit ich das beobachte). In diesem Sinne hast Du recht, das Dutzend scheint auszusterben.

Mit der zweiten Bedeutung wird es aber weiter benutzt.

Answer (score 1):

Ergänzend zur Antwort von Marzipanherz: Der Gebrauch der o.g. zweiten Bedeutung wird auch auf absehbare Zeit nicht aussterben, weil es im Plural als Ersatz für das im Deutschen fehlende "mehrere Zehn" verwendet wird.

Also: Auf German.Stackexchange gibt es *tausende* von Fragen, gestellt von *hunderten* von Mitgliedern, aufgeteilt auf *dutzende* von Tags.
Man könnte einwenden, dass es ja das "-zig" gibt, dessen eigentliche Bedeutung eben "mehrere Zehn" ist, aber das wird eher als Synonym für "(sehr) viele" verstanden, und "Zig Leute haben die Veranstaltung besucht" könnten durchaus auch 200 sein. Darüber hinaus gilt "zig" eher als umgangssprachlich (und ich bin mir  nicht mal sicher, ob es im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum gebräuchlich ist).

Des Weiteren erlaubt der Gebrauch von dutzend eine etwas gröbere Schätzung, wenn man nur die ungefähre Größenordnung angeben will. "Es kamen ca. 4 dutzend Besucher" lässt mehr Spielraum, der Hörer toleriert instinktiv eine größere Diskrepanz zwischen Schätzung und tatsächlicher Zahl, als bei Nennung eines Zahlenwertes "Es kamen ca. 50 Besucher"